# Mongoose pushing a object ID into an array of an existing mongoDB object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a user and profile object. In the user object it has an array variable named profile inside of it (its supposed to store the profile objects by their ID number as reference). They are both successfully created separately but when I try to add the profile into the user (by object ID) and I search it on the mongodb console it turns up as null.

Relevant parts of the code:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   username: String,
   password: String,
   hasProfile: Boolean,
   profile: [
   {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Profile"
   }
   ]
});
```

===================================================================

```
var ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   location: String,
   profilePic: String,
   photoAlbum: {image: String},
   statusUpdates: {image: String},
   newsFeed: {image: String}
});
```

=========================================================

```
app.post("/socialNetwork/createProfile", isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    var currUser = req.user;
    var currUserId = req.user.id;
    var currProfile = req.body.profile;

    Profile.create({
       name: currProfile.name,
       location: currProfile.location
    });

    curUser.profile.push(currProfile.id);
    currUser.save();
});
```

Comment: Hi there. In the `/creatProfile` route handler, are you sure `currProfile.id` value is the user ID? It seems `currUserId` is the variable holding the user ID.

Comment: need to change the type of ```profile``` in ```UserSchema```. make it object not array. ```profile:
   {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Profile"
   }``` Share a sample of your document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to take the _id of the recently created profile and then push it to the profiles array in the user, this _id is created by mongodb is different than whatever in `currProfile.id`

so you can add a callback function to create new profile operation and then take the _id of the added profile from it

```
app.post("/socialNetwork/createProfile", isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    var currUser = req.user;
    var currUserId = req.user.id;
    var currProfile = req.body.profile;

    Profile.create({
       name: currProfile.name,
       location: currProfile.location
    }, function(err, newProfile) {
        if (err) {
            // handle error
        } else {
            // here we can take the _id from the newProfile and add it to the user
            currUser.profile = currUser.profile || []; // double check the profile array, as if this is the first time to push an item to it
            currUser.profile.push(newProfile._id);
            currUser.save();
        }
    });

});
```

> Note that you used `curUser` not `currUser` while pushing the profile._id to the profiles array